# Parametrize Hudson build from the job dashboard

Tags: parameters, hudson, jenkins

I'm using [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) for iOS continuous integration where Hudson starts a shell script. So what I really want to do it's to be able to parametrize a build from the job's dashboard (e.g I want to have a checkbox and if it's ticked I use another branch of the code in my shell script). Is there any plugin for this?

I've seen [Parameterized Build Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Build) but either I don't understand how it's working or it doesn't do what I want

Comment: Can you give more details on what you want to achieve? Do you want to specify the branch to be built as a parameter or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it from the dashboard directly but via the 'Build now' action.

You choose your job, click 'Configure' and on the settings page you choose 'This build is parameterized'. Then you add a parameter - in your case Boolean - and specify the name of your  parameter:[image]

You can then use this parameter as input for your shell script. If you named your parameter FOO, you use $FOO to reference it.

When you choose 'Build now' on that job, you will be asked for the parameters:[image]

Comment: $FOO will then evaluate to "true" or "false".